# How to save to a file the selected path when using dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf

What I tried but not working :

At the bottom of windowMain.xaml.cs I added two new methods for saving and loading :

```
private void SaveFile(string contentToSave, string fileName)
        {
            string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
            string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, fileName);
            File.WriteAllText(saveFilePath, contentToSave);
        }

        private void LoadFile(string loadTo, string fileName)
        {
            string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
            string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, fileName); // add a file name to this path.  This is your full file path.

            if (File.Exists(saveFilePath))
            {
                loadTo = File.ReadAllText(saveFilePath);
            }
        }
```

Then for saving in two places :

```
private void btnRadarFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VistaFolderBrowserDialog dlg = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
            dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                SaveFile(textBoxRadarFolder.Text, "radarpath");
                textBoxRadarFolder.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void btnSatelliteFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VistaFolderBrowserDialog dlg = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();
            dlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                SaveFile(textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text, "satellitepath");
                textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
```

And for loading at the top :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadFile(textBoxRadarFolder.Text, "radarpath");
            LoadFile(textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text, "satellitepath");
```

But it does nothing no errors no exceptions it's just not loading anything back to the textboxes when running the application and I selected folders  first but nothing.

Update :

Saving is working fine.

The problem is with the loading :

At the top I'm doing when running the application :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadFile(textBoxRadarFolder.Text, "radarpath.txt");
            LoadFile(textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text, "satellitepath.txt");
```

But then at the bottom in the LoadFile method I see that the control text to load the content to is empty for some reason even if I entered both textboxes.text to read back it's empty :

The variable loadTo is empty and it should be the textBoxes of the radar and satellite. Why loadTo is empty ?

```
private void LoadFile(string loadTo, string fileName)
        {
            string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
            string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, fileName); // add a file name to this path.  This is your full file path.

            if (File.Exists(saveFilePath))
            {
                loadTo = File.ReadAllText(saveFilePath);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working I just wonder in case the control in the LoadFile is not TextBox but let's say for example RichTextBox ?

It's working now for my needs but what if I wanted to make the LoadFile method something more generic for any control that have text property content like RichTextBox or Label ? Now I'm using TextBox.

```
LoadFile(textBoxRadarFolder, "radarpath.txt");
LoadFile(textBoxSatelliteFolder, "satellitepath.txt");
```

And

```
private void LoadFile(TextBox loadTo, string fileName)
        {
            string applicationPath = Path.GetFullPath(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory); // the directory that your program is installed in
            string saveFilePath = Path.Combine(applicationPath, fileName); // add a file name to this path.  This is your full file path.

            if (File.Exists(saveFilePath))
            {
                loadTo.Text = File.ReadAllText(saveFilePath);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Normally you don't set the control values directly. You would assign the string value to a public property and bind it to the control, In case of a RichTextBox you would have to implent a IValueConverter to convert the string to a FlowDocument. If you don't know about data binding read [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview). In your (not recommended) case you can declare the loadTo parameter type as object or UIElement and then check the type and execute the type related operation. But this is generally not recommended.